# "Минуло десять лет" — значение и ударение

Tags: орфоэпия, смысл

У Аванесова:

**ми́нуть,** ми́ну, ми́нет, *прош.* ми́нул, -а, *прич. страд. прош.* ми́нувший, *деепр.* ми́нув — в значении ***исполниться (о возрасте)***

**мину́ть** *и доп.* **ми́нуть,** *буд. 1 л. ед. неуп.,* ми́нет, *прош.* мину́л, -а *и* ми́нул, -а, *прич. действ. прош.* мину́вший *и доп.* ми́нувший, *деепр.* мину́в *и доп.* ми́нув — в значении ***пройти, окончиться, миновать***

Во фразе *"Минуло уж семь лет, как нет с нами..."* какой смысл имеется в виду: исполнилось семь лет или прошло? Соответственно, где ударение должно быть? Мне почему-то хочется сказать *м**и**нуло.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В "Словаре трудностей произношения и ударения в современном русском языке" К. С. Горбачевича (2000 г.) то же самое:

> м**и**нуть и мин**у**ть. В знач. «исполниться (о возрасте)» - 1-е и
>   2-е л. не употр., м**и**нет; прош. м**и**нул, м**и**нула, м**и**нуло.
>   Ему м**и**нуло сорок лет. В знач. «пройти мимо чего-либо; окончиться;
>   миновать» - 1-е л. не употр. м**и**нешь, м**и**нет; прош. мин**у**л,
>   мин**у**ла, мин**у**ло, мин**у**ли. По рассеянности мин**у**л деревню.
>   Опасность мин**у**ла.

https://diffc_ru.academic.ru/3520/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C

Мне кажется, во фразе "Минуло уж семь лет, как нет с нами..." смысл слова "минула" можно понять и так и так: исполнилось 7 лет, прошло 7 лет, так что как скажете, так и будет верно. Я бы тоже произнесла с ударением на первый слог, потому что не вижу здесь значения "окончилось" как "прошло мимо", всё-таки больше здесь "исполнилось", хотя и нет дательного падежа (кому исполнилось?).

Вот в Викисловаре приводится значение:

> 4. то же, что миновать; окончиться, завершиться, пройти (о времени, о каком-либо событии) ◆ [Лизанька:] Светает!.. Ах! как скоро ночь
>      мину́ла! А. С. Грибоедов, «Горе от ума», 1824 г. ◆ Ах, быстро
>      молодость моя / Звездой падучею мелькнула! / Но ты, пора любви,
>      мину́ла / Ещё быстрее: только год / Меня любила Мариула. А. С. Пушкин,
>      «Цыганы», 1824 г. ◆ Минула длинная зима, наступила весна. А. П. Чехов,
>      «В овраге», 1900 г.

А рядом пример:

> ◆ Почти полвека ми́нуло. За несколько минут… И. В. Елагин, «Весёлая
>   компания…», 1976–1982 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского
>   языка) https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C

Видимо, это допустимо.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Людмила, за ответ! А мне хочется сказать мИнуло в моём примере просто по звучанию, и нет ощущения, что значение ближе к "исполнилось". Вполне воспринимается и как "прошло".